# iOS crash for Unity app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am getting a lot of crash reports on xcode with this crash log for my Unity app. I know it's something to do with 'UIKit'. Does anyone know the cause of this error? Thank you.

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread: 0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000183dd92e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000183f7a288 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376 (pthread.c:1484)
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x0000000183d47d0c abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
3 libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x0000000183e11838 free + 636 (malloc.c:1663)
4 libc++.1.dylib 0x00000001834c64ec std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() + 32 (new:234)
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x0000000183d488f0 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 384 (atexit.c:274)
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x0000000183cf225c exit + 24 (exit.c:78)
7 UIKit 0x000000018e240f00 -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 468 (UIApplication.m:6000)
8 UIKit 0x000000018e55f8c4 __98-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability deactivateEventsOnly:withContext:forceExit:completion:]_block_invoke.271 + 336 (_UICanvasLifecycleMonitor.m:528)
9 UIKit 0x000000018e349884 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 296 (UIApplication.m:2519)
10 UIKit 0x000000018e33f958 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 384 (UIApplication.m:2497)
11 UIKit 0x000000018e22451c _afterCACommitHandler + 132 (UIApplication.m:2549)
12 CoreFoundation 0x00000001842fa910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1824)
13 CoreFoundation 0x00000001842f8238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412 (CFRunLoop.c:1934)
14 CoreFoundation 0x00000001842f8884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2948)
15 CoreFoundation 0x0000000184218da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
16 GraphicsServices 0x00000001861fe020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
17 UIKit 0x000000018e238758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
18 texasapp 0x0000000100b376e0 main + 160 (main.mm:33)
19 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000183ca9fc0 start + 4


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000 x1: 0x0000000000000000 x2: 0x0000000000000000 x3:     0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x0000000000000000 x5: 0x0000000000000000 x6: 0x0000000000000001 x7: 0x000000000000016e
x8: 0x0000000008000000 x9: 0x0000000004000000 x10: 0x0000000183f7a110 x11: 0x000000000000000a
x12: 0x0000000000000000 x13: 0x0000000000000033 x14: 0x0000000000000000 x15: 0x0000000000000000
x16: 0x0000000000000148 x17: 0x0000000000000500 x18: 0x0000000000000000 x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x00000001b66dcb40 x21: 0x0000000000000000 x22: 0x0000000000000303 x23: 0x00000001b66dcc20
x24: 0x00000001020b0000 x25: 0x0000000000000005 x26: 0x0000000000000003 x27: 0x0000000000000002
x28: 0x0000000000000002 fp: 0x000000016f2ce540 lr: 0x0000000183f7a288
sp: 0x000000016f2ce510 pc: 0x0000000183dd92e0 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Please update your question with context for what steps you take that lead to this crash.

Comment: The crash is not happening for me. It's happening for my users and then apple sends the crash report to xcode. I have no idea when the crash occurs.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unhandled exception that happened in your code.

To properly debug it, you need to symbolicate it (https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208593516-How-to-symbolicate-iOS-tvOS-crashlogs).

Also, the UIKit is an apple framework that handles all UI. It has a function of killing your app if something unhandled happens. It would be in 100% crash stacks of iOS crashes, it does not mean that it causes the problem. (just telling so you wont be mislead by it)